# CakePHP and jQuery Mobile (Requesthandler conflict)

Tags: cakephp, jquery-mobile

I have set-up a CakePHP application and included jQuery and jQuery Mobile to get mobile-friendly pages.

Now I'd like CakePHP also to react to AJAX responses and added RequestHandler to the $components. Strangely, if I move to another page, CakePHP just shows a blank page. If I then reload that page, the correct pages shows up. If I disable RequestHandler, everything works again as it should.

What am I doing wrong?
- I have added the JsHelper:

```
public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => 'You must be logged in to view this page.',
            'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.'

        ));
   public $helpers = array('Js');
```

and I also included

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery mobile expects to see a whole page on load. When you use RequestHandler you only get the contents from the view file not the layout